# IOS: start a wma after 4 seconds

Tags: ios, xcode, audio

When my app start I want to start a jingle but not immediately, after 4 seconds, where can I set this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the NSTimer class

Something like

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(playJingle:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

will call the method `playJingle:` after a four second delay.